# Cookie policy difference between ApacheHttpTransport and NetHttpTransport

Tags: java, cookies, google-api, google-http-client

I've been having some problems with some POSTS / GETS when I switched from ApacheHttpTransport to NetHttpTransport. After some digging, I think that NetHttpTransport does not set cookies. Is this a correct assessment of NetHttpTransport? (And if so, is there a way to set a cookie policy on NetHttpTransport?)

Answer (score 0):

[This document](http://javadoc.google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.17.0-rc/com/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport.html) may provide you some useful information.

I cannot see any reference to cookies there - maybe you can show what you found. However it says that the Apache version allows more options.

The HttpTransport class I use is [this one](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.17.0-rc/com/google/api/client/googleapis/javanet/GoogleNetHttpTransport.html).